# When we have no information on what is true between X number of choices, how do we determine the most justified guess/choice to be?

Tags: metaphysics

When we have no information on what is true between X number of choices, how do we determine the most justified guess/choice to be? Let's say we have no information on which is true, and then also consider the case where there is some information. How do we determine which choice is the most justified? Is there any framework that allows us to make the best or more probably choice?

Comment: With so little context, it is hard to answer your question. If the choices are truly indistinguishable, then by definition they can't be distinguished. But life is rarely that clear-cut. We base ourselves on prior experience, and heuristics, and make the choice based on what we have to make it and what beliefs we have about possible and likely futures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if options cannot be distinguished by their likelihood, they can usually be distinguished by their value - among choices that are equally likely to be the "right" one, you should typically just pick the easiest/cheapest/best/least detrimental option. Suppose a physician needs to decide on a treatment course for a patient. His two options are that the patient has a deadly disease and needs a very risky surgery, or that the patient is healthy and needs no intervention. If those two options are equally likely, the physician should probably just do nothing. This is essentially an ***expected utility*** viewpoint, which seeks to maximize the value of likely outcomes under uncertainty - if equally likely choices have different values, you should pick the one with the highest value. Basically, among two lotteries with equal probabilities of winning, you should prefer to enter one with a $100M prize rather than a $100 prize.

Answer (score 1):

Your general question falls squarely under the framework of decision theory which is an interdisciplinary topic studied by economists, statisticians, data scientists, psychologists and philosophers, and your specific concern regarding lack or uncertainty of information belong to one type of decisions called *Choice under uncertainty* according to reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_theory):

> The area of choice under uncertainty represents the heart of decision theory. Known from the 17th century (Blaise Pascal invoked it in his famous wager, which is contained in his Pensées, published in 1670), the idea of expected value is that, when faced with a number of actions, each of which could give rise to more than one possible outcome with different probabilities, the rational procedure is to identify all possible outcomes, determine their values (positive or negative) and the probabilities that will result from each course of action, and multiply the two to give an "expected value", or the average expectation for an outcome; the action to be chosen should be the one that gives rise to the highest total expected value.

So under this framework, your right choice should be determined by some optimal expected value calculated from your numerous and potentially infinite amount of choices, otherwise you won't have any information or criterion to help you. Further as Daniel Bernoulli showed in his 1738 influential paper entitled *Exposition of a New Theory on the Measurement of Risk* to resolve St. Petersburg paradox, one should use more advanced expected utility (determined by the rational choice agent) than expected value due to the law of diminishing marginal utility of pretty much anything such as money.

Finally another recent development is normative behavioral decision theory which may be unconditionally helpful for any of your decision from the same reference:

> The work of Maurice Allais and Daniel Ellsberg showed that human behavior has systematic and sometimes important departures from expected-utility maximization. The prospect theory of Daniel Kahneman and Amos Tversky renewed the empirical study of economic behavior with less emphasis on rationality presuppositions. It describes a way by which people make decisions when all of the outcomes carry a risk. Kahneman and Tversky found three regularities – in actual human decision-making, "losses loom larger than gains"; persons focus more on changes in their utility-states than they focus on absolute utilities; and the estimation of subjective probabilities is severely biased by anchoring.